# How to configure mail (smtp) in bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

I have tried to sent a mail whenever bug get posted or edited in to the bugzilla?

Comment: It should all be on Administration, Parameters, Email. Which part are you having problems with? Is this on Windows or Linux or something else? Which MTA do you have installed?

Comment: @Scott or ServerFault - there's at least as many Bugzilla questions on ServerFault as there are on SuperUser (although when I asked one there it didn't get answered, bah). But in its current form this question is unanswerable wherever it is - we need more information from Neelu.

Answer (score 1):

Log on bugzilla by administrator,and then click "Administration-Parameters-Email",depending on your system to be setting.